# Sum of ONLY negative numbers

Tags: c#, loops

C# Loops.
I need help with this question:

Write a program that reads 10 data from the keyboard and add only those that are negative.

I just started class in January an we're in C# loops. I haven't been in school for over 3 weeks now because of the coronavirus. So i'm kinda lost now and we just started online class so big rips to me:(

```
double sum = 0.0d;
double n = 0.0d;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter a number {i}: ");
    n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

if (n < 0)
    sum = n + n;

Console.WriteLine($"{sum}");
```

Here is my code (I'm probably 100% wrong but it's 2am rn and i'm trying);

Thanks! :)

Thank ya'll so much for the help!

Comment: `sum = n + n;` => `sum += n;`

Comment: Currently: You replace `n` for each iteration of the loop, and then (after the loop is completed) set `sum` to `n + n` (i.e. 2n) when the last `n` is negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you're closer than you think. You should adjust the sum *inside* the loop, and it should be adjusted by adding `n` to the current sum rather than setting it to `n + n`.

By adjusting after the loop is finished, you only take the last number in to account. And, by setting `sum` to `n + n`, the sum you end up with will just be twice the last number entered if it was negative, and zero if not.

In other words, something like:

```
double sum = 0.0d;
double n = 0.0d;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter a number {i}: ");
    n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (n < 0)
        sum = sum + n;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{sum}");
```

Answer (score 4):

you are adding to sum outside of your loop ...

move that if into the loop after the assignment of n, add n to sum and not to n and you are good

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to filter for negative numbers is Math.Min(Int,Int) which returns the Minimum of 2 numbers. In this case positive numbers are set to 0.
After each iteration your would do this:

`sum = sum + Math.Min(0, InputNumber)`

Or you can simply use an if clause:

`if (InputNumber < 0) { sum = sum + InputNumber }`

**Note:** Your need to add your numbers inside your loop, otherwise it would only be executed once.